# Interpret plot_trace from PYMC

Tags: time-series, bayesian, pymc

New to Bayesian Modeling and the python library PYMC. Got some confusing result. How would an expert on Bayesian modeling interpret these graphs?

```
with BVAR_model:
    trace = pm.sample(chains=4, random_seed=rng)

az.plot_trace(trace)
```

[image]

After changing the number of lags, from 2 to 4, and applied differencing I got the following result. The right hand side looks better, but the left hand side confuses, strange distribution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those trace plots don't link right. They should look like “hairy, fat caterpillars” i.e. something like the [below](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Traceplot-of-a-Hairy-Caterpillar-Markov-chain-depicting-3000-samples-The-gray-box_fig1_349376132).

[image: ”Hairy, fat caterpillar” trace plot.]

Moreover, they should heave the same means, while on your plots we can clearly see different chains getting stuck at different values. It might suggest that your model is misspecified and theatre are [identifability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability) issues, by the [folk theorem of statistical computing](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2008/05/13/the_folk_theore/).

Comment: identifiability could definitively be an issue. I extended the number of lags in this BVAR model and applied differencing. There should be a correlation between the two time series I'm modeling, but perhaps not a very strong one.